# Using ExcelBuilder.js with FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, excel, download

In my application I cant use Downloadify (which is recommended by ExcelBuilder.js) so I tried to download my .xlsx file with FileSaver.js

I tried both

```
var blob = new Blob([builder.createFile(basicReport.prepare())],{
  type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base65"
})
saveAs(blob, "myXLSX.xlsx");
```

and

```
var blob = new Blob([builder.createFile(basicReport.prepare())],{
  type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=charset=utf-8"
})
saveAs(blob, "myXLSX.xlsx");
```

I can download the file and i tried .xls and .xlsx extensions as well. The Excel cant open the .xlsx and if i try to open the .xls it opens but the data is uninterpretable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 14-Sep-2017:** there is a simpler code for this as you can see at https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/262#issuecomment-256602092. You can remove the `new Blob` line and just use:

```
ExcelBuilder.Builder.createFile(workbook, {type:'blob'})
  .then(function(blob) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'File.xlsx');
  });
```

---

I was having the same issue today, but with the Angular version of FileSaver.js. And I solved it unintentionally. The following code just worked:

```
ExcelBuilder.Builder.createFile(workbook, {type:'blob'})
    .then(function(blob) {
      var data = new Blob([blob], {type:'base64'});
      FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'File.xlsx');
    });
```

My libraries `"angular-file-saver": "1.1.2"` and `"excel-builder-js": "https://github.com/rodrigosaling/excel-builder.js.git#master"` that is a fork of `excel-builder.js#2.0.2`.

Some clarifications (because it was not 100% *unintentional*):

- the `{type:'blob'}` came from 
  https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js/issues/4#issuecomment-54961321;
- the `createFile()` returns a promise and not a file (without the `then()` the library will create a file containing a "Promise" text on the first cell);
- my fork of the library is to replace the `generate()` by `generateAsync()` on JSZip library. `generate()` was [replaced on v3](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/CHANGES.html) that is the version ExcelBuilder requests;
- why the `{type:'base64'}`? It's only a guess, but I think is what an Excel file is after its content is zipped. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt make it with fileSaver.js library so I made a link in my event handler, clicked it and then removed the link.

```
var myA = document.createElement('a');
myA.setAttribute('href', "'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,' + EB.createFile(workbook));
myA.setAttribute('download', "myXLSX.xlsx");
document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(myA);
myA.click();
document.getElementById("mydiv").removeChild(myA);
```